# How do you read sections of a text file in java?

Tags: java

I need to read a section of a text file, ask the user to answer it, then print the next section of the text file. For example:

> Q1) What is 1 + 1 equal to?
>   (1) 2
>   (2) 3
>   (3) 1
>   (4) 5
>   Q2) What is 2 + 3 equal to?
>   (1) 5
>   (2) 4
>   (3) 7
>   (4) 9
>   Q3) What is 2 + 8 equal to?
>   (1) 10
>   (2) 7
>   (3) 11
>   (4) 13

I want to display the first question and its multiple choice answers - ("Q1) What is 1 + 1 equal to? (1) 2 (2) 3 (3) 1 (4) 5"),
then take in the user's input, then display the second question from the text file and so on.

Here is what I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    String lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("History.txt")).get(i);
    System.out.println(lines);
    iUserInput = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (iUserInput == 1)
    {
        iScore = iScore + 1;
    }
}
```

This is just a prototype, but I can only get it to read a few lines. After that, it stops. I don't know how to print out another section after this one.

How would I get it working?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Read all the lines just once. Then iterate through all the lines one by one. You are reading the file 3 times which is not needed.

Comment: I see your edits now. In order for program to determine whether the user's answer is right or not, it needs to know the right answer itself. How would your program figure out the right answer of a question?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your input has each question on its own line, each answer on its own line, and each question starts with "Q" you could do something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> lines;
try {
    lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("History.txt"));

    int index = 0;
    while(index < lines.size()){
        do{
            System.out.println(lines.get(index));
            index++;
        }while(index < lines.size() && !lines.get(index).startsWith("Q"));

        System.out.println("What is your answer?");
        int answer = scanner.nextInt();
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    // Problem reading the file, print the stack trace
    e.printStackTrace();
}

scanner.close();
```

However, your program has no way to know which answer is the correct one. I doubt you want to hard-code the correct answers as you have done in your existing code:

```
if (iUserInput == 1)
{
    iScore = iScore + 1;
}
```

So you could add some additional data to your file or perhaps create a second file with answers in it to use as the "answer key". Then you would use the "answer key" to see if the user entered the correct answer or not and take appropriate action.

Note: with the code above if the user does not enter an integer a `java.util.InputMismatchException` will be thrown. So you should handle this possibility somehow - probably by telling the user they made a mistake and give them another try. You will also want to validate user input to ensure that the user enters a value in the correct range, i.e. 1 through 4 inclusive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer but when I use the: List<String> lines; It gives this error: The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Comment: Did you import the List interface? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Also make sure your import is for java.util.List

Comment: I'm using java eclipse